# Determine length of optical fiber

Tags: optics, measurements, fiber-optics

Say I have 1 km of the optical fiber on a reel. But I only need 200 m of it and I don't have a right optical source or say I don't want to lose time coupling the light into the fiber. I also don't want to damage it. What is the best way to measure a right amount of it?

1. **"Just measure 5 m, and then again 5 m and so on until I get 200 m"**. It took to long, I can damage the fiber and I definitely need a friend to do it. It is also questionable how accurate am I.
2. **"I can weigh it"**. If I now how much 1 meter weighs, the task becomes trivial
3. **"Make some calculations"**. I measure the radius up to the upper
   layer of the fiber on my reel, calculate the length of the circumference and then rotate the right number. I have of course make some assumptions like that after every 10 rotations (the reel is quite broad) my diameter becomes less by the doubled diameter of the fiber.

What would be the most accurate, faster and safe method to do it?
Thanks

Comment: To what precision do you need to measure it? What is the use case, and why can't you just use the full 1000m? What balance of accurate/fast/safe are you going for (schedule, budget, performance: pick two!). Currently not clear enough to answer.

Comment: Jon, It would be good if I get something between 199.5 and 200.5 m. I need to divide 1 km fiber into five 200 m parts.  I would say I must avoid any damage to the fiber, it must be accurate enough and it must not take longer than 30 min pro 200 m. And I have no budget to buy very expensive instruments.

Comment: Buy laser rangefinder (they exist with sufficient specs - they are under $1000), or borrow a friendly Civil engineer with an accurate transit (cheaper). Find a big field. Roll out cable until it is 200m long using the rangefinder or transit. Cut, roll again.

Comment: Depending on the accuracy you need, measure and cut a string, and then use that as a guide.  That way your measuring process doesn't have to be so concerned with not breaking the fiber, and if it doesn't work perfectly, you can cut a new string.

Comment: Using which instrument can I measure?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest finding a second spool of known (and preferably large) diameter. Then set up a peg-board with both spools mounted vertically next to one another on pegs to form axles, and turn the second spool in order to transfer a length of the $1$ km fiber onto it.

You'll have to gently use a tool or your fingers to make sure the windings on the second spool form nice layers by guiding them to one side. From the thickness of the second spool along its axis of symmetry, you can find how many windings can be placed next to one another before forming a full layer. You can then calculate how many turns of the second spool you need to get $200$ meters.

If the fiber is thin enough relative to your second spool's diameter, you may be able to neglect the increasing diameter of subsequent layers as they form on the second spool, or you may have to account for this. This will depend on whether your fiber is cladded or bare. Regardless of whether your fiber is cladded or bare, I would strongly recommend against taking it into a big field, or really any large space where people are likely to step on it.